# How can I target WordPress 3.8 new interface MP6 with CSS?

Tags: admin, css

When [MP6 was a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mp6/) in WordPress 3.6+ it changes the body class of the admin and added an "admin-mp6" class which helps me to style my plugin accordingly.

Now with the latest Alpha of WordPress 3.8 the class was removed. I know since it's an alpha version the class may come back but I wonder if there are any official "best practices"

Comment: This may be useful - http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/11/19/targeting-the-new-dashboard-design-in-a-post-mp6-world/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andrew Nacin](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/author/nacin/) posted some "offical" approach to this topic [here](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/11/19/targeting-the-new-dashboard-design-in-a-post-mp6-world/)

The CSS only variant should use the branch-3-x class to target the versions **before** 3.8 and the defaults should get applied to all upcoming versions so you don't have to care about further version:

```
.branch-3-6 .some-selector,
.branch-3-7 .some-selector {
     /* some rules go here for 3.6 and 3.7 */
}
.some-selector {
     /* 3.8+ rules go here */
}
```

[Read more about](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/11/19/targeting-the-new-dashboard-design-in-a-post-mp6-world/) this topic on the make.wordpress.org page

Answer (score 4):

While it's not *specific* to MP6 (I am not following its development) and its CSS, to me your question sounds like "how to check that WP version is equal to greater than one some feature was introduced in?".

So I would just examine content of `$wp_version` global. If it's 3.8 feature then anything with fitting version has it.

Also from quick look at `body` classes in admin there is `branch-3-7` class, which makes possible to target `branch-3-8` (however cannot be targeted conditionally as anything >=3.8 since that's not something CSS does).

Comment: I would prefer a CSS-only variant. Maybe it will be added in the final version. I just thought that there should be an "official" way

Comment: The .mp6 class will not be coming back, as it was there for the needs of the mp6 plugin itself; keeping it now that mp6 *is* the admin interface would be pretty pointless and unsemantic.

As Rarst points out, there is the new branch-3-n class and also a version-3-n class available.

Comment: Why not use detection via `if ( 'mp6' === get_user_option( 'admin_color' ) )` ?

Comment: I really don't like to alter the body class on the backend with my plugin (to add a mp6 class) since it's not only plugin pages rather on every backend page. I may add a ticket to the WP trac

Answer (score 3):

I also prefer a CSS-only variant. Unfortunately, that's not entirely possible.  The route I'm taking is a hybrid of CSS and PHP.

First, we use PHP to detect the version of WordPress installed and, optionally, whether or not MP6 is installed.  This is fairly easy using the `MP6` constant defined by the plugin and the `$wp_version` global as suggested by Rarst.  Once we know we're living in an MP6 world, we add our own body class.  I'm choosing to use the class name "flaticons":

```
/**
 * Filter body classes to detect MP6 or WordPress 3.8 so we can substitute the correct styles.
 *
 * @param array $classes
 *
 * @global $wp_version
 *
 * @return array
 */
function flaticons_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $wp_version;

    if ( ( defined( 'MP6' ) && MP6 ) || version_compare( $wp_version, '3.8', '>=' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'flaticons';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Now, in our CSS wherever we were previously using the `.admin-mp6`, `.admin-color-mp6`, or `.mp6` selectors, we can use `.flaticons` instead.

This will work both with MP6 on older installs and WordPress 3.8+ once it's released.  Not optimal, but a solid, future-proof solution.

Comment: You should check if the `flaticons` body class has already been added, to avoid duplication